# How to keep a single XPO across different versions?

Tags: versioning, axapta, x++, xpo

I want to have one XPO, and have the same code work on AX4 and AX5. I am looking for a precompiler directive to check the version, sort of like:

```
#if define AX4
  thisCode(...)
#else
  thatCode(...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `SysDataExpImp` macro library may have a version based macro called `expFormat` which you could use like this:

```
#SysDataExpImp
#if.expFormat('EXPFORMAT VER. 5.0')
info('Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009');
#endif
#if.expFormat('EXPFORMAT VER. 4.01')
info('Microsoft Dynamics AX 4.0 SP1');
#endif
```

You could also use a macro that is only found in AX 2009. The `AotExport` macro library has macros for each type of AOT object and Data Sets were introduced in 2009:

```
#AotExport
#if.expDataSet
info('Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009');
#endif
#ifnot.expDataSet
info('older than Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009');
#endif
```